# VB with dynamic webservice URL

Tags: vb.net, web-services

Confused. Writing a VB app that uses a webservice. The URL for this webservice will change based on where the app is running from so I need to change it at runtime. I see that by default the web reference URL has its behavior set to "Dynamic" which means I should be able to change it at runtime, but at the same time the app.config file has the Scope set to "Application," which means it's read-only at runtime. I'm looking to use `My.Settings.WebServiceURL = "new url"` but in order to do this the scope has to be set to User... I think. But if that's the case then what does the "Dynamic" behavior do for me? Can someone give me a code example of how I can change this at runtime? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just can't find the answer to this question on SO that I used several months ago doing the same thing... If there's no answer in 12 hours I'll review the code I wrote and post the answer.

Comment: @Dmitry - Thanks! Amazingly I can't find a clear answer anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just write some code to change the WebService [Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.webclientprotocol.url.aspx) property from a setting?

```
oService.Url = sNewUrl
```

You could use a regular expression to allow you to only specify the url root e.g. `http://ws.test.com/` and have that applied to any service that needed moving.

Comment: Obviously I didn't know the Url property existed or I probably wouldn't have posted this question, right?

Comment: @JJD - I'm glad that this works for you, we do something similar in our production code as it allows us to dynamically move users to a diferent server. Remember that you can change the port if required by using standard port notation in the url `http://ws.test.com:888/test.asmx`

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, create a class which will become your web service client:

```
Public Class WS_ClientClass
Private MyService As MyWebServiceSoap

Public Sub New()
    MyService = New MyWebServiceSoapClient
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal strHost As String, ByVal strPort As String)
    'Set up the binding element to match the app.config settings '
    Dim binding = New BasicHttpBinding()
    binding.Name = "MyWebServiceSoap"
    binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
    binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
    binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
    binding.AllowCookies = False
    binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = False
    binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard
    binding.MaxBufferSize = 65536
    binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288
    binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text
    binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered
    binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = True

    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 8192
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 16384
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 4096
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384

    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None
    binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None
    binding.Security.Transport.Realm = ""
    binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName
    binding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default

    'Define the endpoint address'
    Dim endpointStr = "http://" & strHost & ":" & strPort & "/MyWebApp/MyWebService.asmx"
    Dim endpoint = New EndpointAddress(endpointStr)

    MyService = New MyWebServiceSoapClient(binding, endpoint)
End Sub
```

This implementation allows you to both use default settings from the Service Reference (first overload of the constructor) as well as custom settings specified in the code (second overload).

Comment: I wish I could find the original answer to credit... Helped me a lot.